# System of differential equations (in X, Y): expression of Y.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find an expression for the function $Y(t)$ by the following system
\begin{align}
\frac{d X (t)}{dt} & =-\alpha Y \\[6pt]
\frac{d Y (t)}{dt} & =\sigma \beta Y^2-(\beta+\gamma) Y - \sigma X Y+X
\end{align}
The equation must contain only $Y$ and not $X$.

$\alpha, \beta, \sigma$ are real parameters. Does anyone have any suggestions for me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ just "typical" functions from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, or are these matrices (I see capital letters), or??

Comment: And $\gamma$ is also a real parameter, right?

Comment: @Mark: Please look at my edit.  $\LaTeX$ and MathJax have a standard method of vertically aligning the "$=$"s on two different lines.  It appears you tried to do that by a method that might not survive copying and pasting into another document.

Comment: Thank you Michael Hardy. Yes, anorton, X and Y are typical functions from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $X(t)=-\alpha\int_0^tY(s)ds$ and put this in the second equation, or  solve $X$ in terms of $Y$ and its derivatives from the second equation and then take the derivative of $X$ and substitute this in the first one. Namely $X=\frac{Y'-\sigma \beta Y^2+(\beta+\gamma) Y}{1-\sigma Y}$ and use the quotient rule to find $X'$. Plugging this into the first equation you will have an equation involving only $Y$ and its derivatives.

Comment: Thank you. I have obtained $Y''=2\sigma\beta Y Y'-(\beta+\gamma)Y'+\sigma\alpha Y^2-\alpha Y -\frac{\sigma Y'}{1-\sigma Y}\left[Y'-\sigma\beta Y^2+(\beta+\gamma)Y\right]$. This formula seems very complicated and inelegant. You've got a different result, and more elegant?